# One shot manga about two strangers that meet each other in heaven

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this one shot years ago like around 2007? All I can remember is it was a one shot about a guy and a girl that die and are complete strangers. They meet in the afterlife and talk about their lives. Eventually God is willing to give one of them a second chance and they fight over who should get it saying the other person deserves it more. In the end the girl gets a second chance I think...

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a good start with detail. If you remember anything else at all though please [edit] that detail into the question. For example, did you read this online? If so can you remember what site? When you say they fight, do you mean an actual physical fight or more of an argument? Do we see anything that happens after she gets a second chance or does it end there? Why does God give one of them a second chance? etc.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar memory of a one-shot just like you described and after almost 6 years I found it (hopefully it's the own you're looking for)

Name: Happiness upon you / 幸せをあなたに / Shiawase wo Anata ni
By: Avogado6

(If it's not what you meant, sorry and hope someone else can help)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It would be great to get this old question answered; can you provide some more details about this, so it's possible to see how well it matches the question?

Comment: Note: This looks reasonably likely.  Boy was killed by abusive dad, girl bullied into suicide, meet in line for reincarnation.  Get randomly assigned their next life; boy gets a good life with good parents, girl gets abusive family.  As they wait for their turn, boy asks to look at her ticket, shows her his.  As his number comes up he runs through the reincarnation gate with her ticket, ensuring she gets a good life.  (They don't fight, though, he simply tricks her.)